# choose default view with PDF objects

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, cross-browser

I am using HTML 5 object tags to embed PDFs on my pool teams website. On Safari, the PDF automatically fits to the width that I've assigned to the div that the PDF displays in. On Chrome, the PDF size is set to fullsized, so it looks zoomed at first.

Here's my code

```
<object data="docs/Pool Schedule.pdf?#view=fitH" type="application/pdf" width="660" height="440">
    <param name="view" value="fitH" />
</object>
```

I have added a parm tag as well as appended `?#view=fitH` in attempts to get another default view. Neither seems to do anything .

I'm wondering if there's a way default all browsers to the fit width view (screenshot 2).

If you want to view the website, it's [Kingston8Ball.com](http://kingston8ball.com/schedule.php)

note: I realize both photos are with Chrome, but for simplicity I just took the second screenshot with the same browser and the desired view rather than switching browsers.

[image: full size view]

[image: Fit width view]

Comment: When I open your site in Chrome, I am seeing second view. What changes do you require?

Comment: I've looked on 3 machines using Chrome and none of them default to the second view. I'm not sure how you got so lucky.

Comment: If it helps I am using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I've tried the same version of Chrome on W7 and OSX Maverick. Neither show's it the way I want. BUT Safari on OSX does.

Comment: Hey, it could actually be due to some pdf extension I have installed. Because I just noticed, it looks like this: http://imgur.com/Ng0KbZQ

Comment: Yes, that's not the default chrome DPF viewer. Must be your extension. Thanks for adding that note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly the answer I was looking for in my question, but it's an alternative solution with minimal effort. I ended up using [Viewer JS](http://viewerjs.org/examples/). With this tool I just copy the JS source files to the root of my website and then add the following line to my HTML files where I want the PDF iFrame to appear.

```
<iframe frameBorder="" id="viewer" src = "http://kingston8ball.com/ViewerJS#/docs/League Rules 2015.pdf" width='650' height='500' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```